# Windows 10 file association, does not hold from search menu

Tags: audio, windows-10, mp3, file-association, windows-search

I am facing a weird problem, I am using foobar (latest as of now, 1.3.8) to play mp3's in Windows 10,
foobar is set as the default app for music, as is the '.mp3' extension,

when I open an mp3 file from the file explorer, or with a run command it opens fine with foobar.

the problem is that when I try to open an mp3 from the search bar, the "how to you want to open this file" dialog always pops up:

[image]

I also noticed that in 'hkey_classes_root/.mp3' the '(Default)' key is empty,

how do I register foobar to open mp3's from the search menu?